# How to make inline C++ function calls in R?

Tags: c++, r, inline, rcpp

All right, so I'm programming in R and I want to make a C++ function. I've imported the Rcpp and inline libraries. For right now, I'm just trying to make a simple function that adds 2 numbers, but no matter what I try, I get errors.

Here's my code:

```
cppstring = 'double ss = RcppSexp(s).asDouble(); return RcppSexp(ss+4).asSexp();'
hi <- cfunction(body=cppstring, signature(s="double"), Rcpp = TRUE)
```

and when I enter that second line, I get

```
file628a34ce.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* file628a34ce(SEXPREC*)’:
file628a34ce.cpp:9: error: ‘RcppSexp’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [file628a34ce.o] Error 1

ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

Program source:
1: #include <Rcpp.h>
2: 
3: 
4: extern "C" {
5:   SEXP file628a34ce ( SEXP s );
6: }
7: 
8: SEXP file628a34ce ( SEXP s ) {
9: double ss = RcppSexp(s).asDouble(); return RcppSexp(ss+4).asSexp();
10:   Rf_warning("your C program does not return anything!");
11:   return R_NilValue;
12: }
Error in compileCode(f, code, language, verbose) : 
Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! file628a34ce.cpp: In function    ‘SEXPREC* file628a34ce(SEXPREC*)’:
file628a34ce.cpp:9: error: ‘RcppSexp’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [file628a34ce.o] Error 1
```

I've tried everything I could possibly think of, from casting, to moving code around, to #including RcppSexp, to just plain returning s, and every time I get some error, whether it's

```
cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘SEXPREC*’ in return
```

or

```
invalid use of undefined type ‘struct SEXPREC’
```

or

```
forward declaration of ‘struct SEXPREC’
```

...I'm so confused :( I've looked at several examples online, and what I currently have seems to be what everyone else is doing, and it magically works for them...

What is this SEXPREC* thing I keep seeing everywhere? And what is that extern "C" function thing that it makes? And why does it generate statements AFTER my return statement and tell me that my function doesn't return anything, even though it does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there a reason you are not starting from the (literally!!) dozens of Rcpp examples using inline?

Also, what on earth is RcppSexp? What documentation are your following?

Here is an example I did last night for someone on the rcpp-devel (which you should probably join):

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

xorig <- c(1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7)

code <- '
    Rcpp::NumericVector x(xs);
    Rcpp::NumericVector xa = sapply( x, ::fabs );
    return(xa);
    '

xabs <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="numeric"),
                    plugin="Rcpp",
                    body=code)

xabs(xorig)
```

This is a more advanced example as it uses *Rcpp sugar* to give us vectorised expression *a la R* in C++, which we demonstrate here with a the simple `sapply()` from *Rcpp sugar*:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> library(inline)
R> 
R> xorig <- c(1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7)
R> 
R> code <- '
+     Rcpp::NumericVector x(xs);
+     Rcpp::NumericVector xa = sapply( x, ::fabs );
+     return(xa);
+     '
R> 
R> xabs <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="numeric"),
+                     plugin="Rcpp",
+                     body=code)
R> 
R> xabs(xorig)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
R>
```

This most clearly demonstrates two of your requests: we use the *implicit* template converters `as<>()` to go from a `SEXP` given from R to the initial vector, and then use the *implicit* template converter `wrap()` to return the transformed second vector.

All this is explained in detail in the Rcpp-introduction vignette and the other vignettes in the Rcpp documentation,.

Comment: Well... I was following the example here: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2009/12/20/#rcpp_inline_example. Is that not yours?

And umm, could you perhaps give me an example of what what I'm trying to do should look like? (Take a number from R, have C++ add it to another number, then return it back to R)

Comment: Ok, fair enough, so it uses the deprecated old Rcpp interface now in RcppClassic.  As for taking a single number and returning a single number, you can either do what I using the vectorised forms (via implicit template wrappers) and just access the first element, or you can use explicit `as<double>(x)` and `wrap(y)`.  Keep reading the blog forward --- there are a dozen or more examples just there.  And read the other documentation.  It is all there for you.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing:  the old examples you find via the old blog posts will of course still work ... against the then current version.  The post you found is very explicit about Rcpp 0.7.0.  As we made several dozen releases since then, some things changed.  We don't usually change the API, but yes, `RcppSexp` has been withdrawn and we have *much* better stuff now.

Comment: All right thanks... I've started reading the introduction, and stuff is actually working now, ha.

Now, is there anywhere I could go to find an API for any of these individual classes? Like, in the NumericVector section in the introduction there was nothing that said whether or not NumericVectors know how long they are, so I had to search around a bit to find that they have a size() function. Is there a place that just lists all these classes and their member functions/data?

Also, are there data types for single values? Or will I always have to represent a single number as a 1-element vector?

Comment: Atomic values work as eg `Rcpp::as<double>(someSexpVar)` as I wrote above.  Keep reading, there are plenty of examples.

Comment: Okeydokey. Thanks. Now about those APIs...?

Comment: See the documentation supplied with the package.

Comment: Now what would I do if I wanted to make a c++ function call other c++ functions (inside R)?

Comment: Right now, I'm just using cxxfunction and passing in all the functions I want included through the `includes` parameter. Is there a better/more "correct" way?

Comment: As I said before, the proper place for longer discussion is the rcpp-devel list.  This has come up before.  It is also in the Rcpp FAQ.